# Cannot set property 'loadSuggestionsAsync' of undefined with in NativeScript RadDataForm

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to get data from Remote Server for an `autocomplete` in `RadDataForm`. I get

> 'loadSuggestionsAsync' of undefined.

The same example is working as expected with `RadAutoCompleteTextView` out of `RadDataForm` but is required inside `RadDataFrom`.

```
<RadDataForm #dataform tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton [source]="person">
                <TKEntityProperty #autocomplete tkDataFormProperty name="name" displayName="Name:" index="0" autoCompleteDisplayMode="Plain" [valuesProvider]="fromProviders">
                    <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="AutoCompleteInline"></TKPropertyEditor>
                </TKEntityProperty>
            </RadDataForm>

@ViewChild("dataform") dataformComponent: RadDataFormComponent;
@ViewChild("autocomplete") autocomplete: RadAutoCompleteTextViewComponent;
ngOnInit(): void {
        this._person = new Person("John", 23, "john@company.com", "New York", "5th Avenue", 11);

        this.jsonUrl = 'myUrl';
        let that = this;
        let options = this.createRequestHeader();
        this.autocomplete.autoCompleteTextView.loadSuggestionsAsync = function (text) {
            console.error(text);
            const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                http.request({
                    url: that.jsonUrl + '/' + text,
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: options,
                }).then(function (r: any) {
                    let d = r.content.toJSON();
                    const items: Array<TokenModel> = new Array();
                    for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                        items.push(new TokenModel(d[i].label, null));
                    }
                    resolve(items);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    alert(err.message);
                    reject();
                });
            });

            return promise;
        };
    }

private createRequestHeader() {
        // set headers here e.g.
        const tokenInfo = appSettings.getString('TokenInfo');
        return {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${tokenInfo}`,
        }
    }

    get fromProviders(): ObservableArray<TokenModel> {
        return this._items;
    }
```

What changes are required in this code.? I am using NativeScript/Angular.

Comment: `OnInit` doesn't guarantee that all the required components are initialised, try `AfterViewInit` or preferably loaded event of the component itself.

Comment: AfterViewInit also produces same error. I suspect something wrong i did in HTML.

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=zxnpxi&v=3

Comment: Now I get what exactly you are trying to do, but it's not the autocomplete plugin directly used within data form but an extended version of the native component. So none of the api methods you read in autocomplete plugin might be valid here. It's best you raise an issue on [UI feedback](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues) repo Or It may be possible if you dig deeper into the plugin's source code.